# Is it possible to use different graphics chips in host and VM?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine

What I'm looking for is some way to configure a Windows/Linux dual system (either one as host, other as VM) where Linux uses my Intel HD chip and Windows uses my GTX 970. Preferably with near native CPU clock speed on the VM OS.

Is this possible? And if so what VM software would be best used to handle it?

Ideally I'd prefer Linux to be the VM OS if possible.

Comment: Not possible in virtualbox(as tagged).  Maybe in VMWare(http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1010789)

Comment: @codemonk113 changed the tag now thanks for spotting. I'll have a look at vmware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMware workstation* can pass though a PCI-e device. This requires a CPU with AMD-Vi or Intel VT-d capability and you cannot use that card on the host running the VMs.

This is usually used to pass though RAID cards, 10Gbit NICs etc directly to a VM, but it can also be used for graphics cards. Note that this assumes a dedicated graphics card separate monitor on that card.

If you try this on a laptop with 'smart switching' between the IGP and a dedicated GPU then this might be a quit a challenge. But running a host on one card and a VM with another card should just work.

Some more links:

- [KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/How_to_assign_devices_with_VT-d_in_KVM)
- [Qemu](https://wiki.debian.org/VGAPassthrough)
- [Deadrat and xen](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Virtualization/chap-Virtualization-PCI_passthrough.html)
- [Vmware ESX - old](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1010789)

---

*And likely other virtualisation software though I have no experience with that.